# Is it possible to submit a form with onpaste?

Tags: javascript, html, onpaste

I'm trying to make a form that once you paste something it self submit. I have the following code:

```
<form>
    <textarea onpaste=submit></textarea>
</form>
```

javascript code I've tried:

```
<form action="./1.php" method="post" id="frm1" name="frm1"> 
<textarea placeholder="Paste Here" onpaste="document.frm1.submit()"></textarea>
```

Previous code was not working for some reason.

What javascript code should I use to make it work?

Comment: what javascript have you tried to make it work?

Comment: For some reason it wasn't working. I used this now and worked

`<form action="./1.php" method="post" id="frm1" name="frm1">
<textarea placeholder="Paste Here" onpaste="document.frm1.submit()"></textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. It will automatically submit the form once anything is pasted inside:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form id="myform"><textarea></textarea></form>
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("paste", function() {
   this.submit();
  });
</script>
</html
```